# Filter on bridged vlan interface with iptables

Tags: iptables, bridge, vlan

I have the following network configuration: `eth0.100 and eth.101 bridged to br100-101`.  I need to filter out incoming traffic on eth0.100 based on source mac address.  The traffic goes allowed traffic goes transparently from vlan100 to vlan101.  But it looks like I've missed something.  The simple rule

```
iptables -N VLAN100
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0.100 -j VLAN100
```

doesn't catch anything.  More over `-m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables catch: "` logs only `lo` and `eth0` without tagged traffic.  Probably ebtables could be a solution, but it seems it does not support time based filtering I need.  I am sure this scheme was working some time ago, but probably that was FreeBSD.

OS Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: See if the `FORWARD` chain would see the packets?

Comment: @ilkkachu checked once more - now it see.  Now I need to find out which additional nf module triggered.  Initially counters were zero.